# Space separated string parameter in Jenkins String Parameter

Tags: jenkins, keyword

I have a string parameter in jenkins called '`Keywords`'.
I set the value of `Keywords = "Google,Microsoft,Uber Go"`.
But jenkins string parameter takes only till `"Google,Microsoft,Uber"` and truncates `"Go"` automatically.

Due to this my code runs incorrectly.
Can anyone help in handling this auto-truncate issue in jenkins string parameter?

This string parameter is used in my python code where I split the Keywords on comma(,) and use the 3 generated words for operation in my code. But jenkins is truncating "Go" automatically due to which incorrect word is processed by my code.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution for this. 
While calling the string parameter variable "Keywords" put in Double  quotes. Shell script command to be put in Jenkins :
python script.py "${Keywords}"